# Circumference of circle is divided into n equal parts

Tags: circles, polygons

***Question*** -

Circumference of circle is divided into n equal parts, prove that

1) points of division are vertices of regular polygon

2) tangents at points of division are sides of regular polygon

***My try*** -

I proved first as this - because equal arcs cutoff equal chords therefore all sides will be equal...and also equal arcs subtends equal angles at centre so all interior angles will be equal ....

I am able to prove 2) for n=3,4 but not able to generalize this..

Comment: In case 2) the circle becomes inscribed circle. To see this, draw 3 tangents (which will be the edges) and get 2 vertexes where those tangents intersect. Now consider the triangle whose vertexes are the those of 2 and the center of the circle. I am sure you will notice there will be $n$ such triangles if you keep drawing tangents and will notice the central angle should be $360^{\circ}/n$.

Comment: I do same as uu told ..but I did not able to understand why angles will be 360 / n and how this helps in proving that tangents are sides of regular polygon...can you please give  more details and write the answer ...

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Let $A$, $C$ and $E$ be tangent points. You can easily notice that $OB$ and $OD$ are angle bisectors of $AOC$ and $COE$ respectively. From your proof of 1), you know the angle $AOC$ and $COE$ are equal to $\dfrac{360^{\circ}}{n}$. Hence, this gives you the angle $BOD$ is also equal to $\dfrac{360^{\circ}}{n}$. I hope this picture and explanations clarify all the question marks in your head.

Comment: Thanks for writing...but how proving that BOD=360/n helps in proving that it is regular polygon ?

Comment: Waiting for your reply..

Answer (score 0):

Rotate the figure around the center of the circle such that the first point maps to the second points. By the given equidistance, it follows that the $k$th point maps to the $(k+1)$st point (and the $n$th point to the first). Then the tangents at the $n$ points are mapped in the same cyclic fashion. i.e., the polygon formed by them has precisely the symmetry of a regular $n$-gon ...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The figure is invariant under the rotations of the group generated by the rotation of angle $\frac{2\pi}n$, hence all sides of the polygon the circle is inscribed in are isometric.